# How to automatically get refresh token and replace to previous html in autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I got stock on how to get token. Pls do you have any tutorial on how to get refresh token? Thanks!I currently know how to show a model in a viewer, however, the token will be expire every 2 hours. It is frustrated for me to search online for how to get token. Pls could u help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Forge tokens expire after 30min. You don't have to search randomly online for articles, you can simply use our Forge blog, where all Forge resources are... https://forge.autodesk.com/blog. Alternatively check the documentation at https://developer.autodesk.com

Answer (score 0):

These two articles should be of help.

[About Refresh Token](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/about-refresh-token)

[Landing your Forge OAuth authentication workflow](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/landing-your-forge-oauth-authentication-workflow.html)

When requesting an access_token you'll also get back a refresh token that will enable you to get a new access_token without the user having to log in again.
Depending on which programming language and environment you are using you can also use our SDK's to make your life easier. 
E.g. in case of Node.js you can just **npm install** our **forge-api** package that will have the necessary functions to request an access_token

The steps are:

1) Redirect the user to the Autodesk log-in page (change both the client_id and redirect_uri to match the values that is used by your registered Forge application):
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&scope=data:read

2) Implement in your application the endpoint that you specified for your Forge application's redirect_uri

3) Using the token you got back above request an access_token
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken

4) When you need a new access_token you can use the refresh_token that the gettoken endpoint also returned: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/refreshtoken